# Join on different tables depending on column associated with value being joined on?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to create a view that provides different tables depending on a column associated with the value being joined on.

Example:

```
SomeTable
+-----+------+
| ID  | Type |
+-----+------+
| 123 |    1 |
| 124 |    2 |
| 125 |    1 |
| 126 |    2 |
+-----+------+

TableA
+---------+---------------+-----+------------+
| Item_ID | Serial_Number | ID  | LocationID |
+---------+---------------+-----+------------+
|       1 | 19-001        | 124 |          4 |
|       2 | 19-002        | 126 |         17 |
+---------+---------------+-----+------------+

TableB
+-----+------------+----------+
| ID  | LocationID | Quantity |
+-----+------------+----------+
| 123 |          7 |       15 |
| 125 |         12 |       10 |
+-----+------------+----------+

SELECT t.ID, v.LocationID
FROM SomeTable t
FULL JOIN NewView v ON t.ID = v.ID
WHERE t.ID = 123
```

If the ID the view is being joined on is Type 1 then the View selects Table A. If the ID is Type 2, then select Table B.

The expected result for ID 123 would be:

```
+-----+------------+
| ID  | LocationID |
+-----+------------+
| 123 |          7 |
+-----+------------+
```

And the expected result for ID 124 would be:

```
+-----+------------+
| ID  | LocationID |
+-----+------------+
| 124 |          4 |
+-----+------------+
```

I know I could do this by using a function and passing a parameter like this:

```
SELECT t.ID, f.LocationID
FROM SomeTable t
FULL JOIN NewFunction(123) f ON t.ID = f.ID
WHERE t.ID = 123
```

And here is the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION NewFunction (@ID)
RETURNS @ReturnTable TABLE (ID INT, LocationID INT)
BEGIN
     DECLARE @Type INT
     SET @Type = (SELECT Type FROM SomeTable WHERE ID = @ID)

     IF @Type = 1
          INSERT INTO @ReturnTable (ID, LocationID)
          SELECT t.ID, a.LocationID
          FROM SomeTable t
          FULL JOIN TableA a
          WHERE t.ID = @ID
     ELSE
          INSERT INTO @ReturnTable (ID, LocationID)
          SELECT t.ID, b.LocationID
          FROM SomeTable t
          FULL JOIN TableB b
          WHERE t.ID = @ID
     RETURN
END
```

The problem is that passing a parameter to a function like this will require making changes to the application. I would prefer not to have to implement these changes, so it would be ideal if I could recreate the functionality in the example above either with a view or a function that does not require a parameter. Any ideas?

Comment: Show us some sample table data for the involved tables. And also the expected result.

Comment: A view can join multiple tables and combine the results to look like they came from one, e.g. combining home, work and mobile telephone numbers from separate tables into a single column by using outer joins and `coalesce`. What a view can't do is reach out through the aether to discern the environment in which it is being used and alter its behavior based thereon: "Well, if you're going to join on my `ShoeWidth` column with a _Unicode_ column then I'm going to return ... ." You could nest the view in a larger view that contains the additional logic, but I don't think that's what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create a view for all three tables?

```
select t.id, coalesce(a.locationid, b.locationid) as locationid
from sometable t left join
     a
     on t.id = a.id and t.type = 1 left join
     b
     on t.id = b.id and t.type = 2;
```

You need the `type` to get the right table, so it seems that all three tables should be used together.

Comment: So actually I think something like this might work.  I think just making a view from TableA and TableB will give me the result I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a parameter into a VIEW, so it isn't possible to make it do different things depending on the content of the select query.

What you could do, is to use a UNION query assuming that Table A and Table B have the same columns, then use the Type column in your WHERE clause

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer